# When will MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate return MessageComposeResultFailed?

Tags: ios

I create an In-App SMS application, I can send SMS/iMessage. And I have implement MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, but I have one question: when the result of the delegate return MessageComposeResultFailed? I have tried a lot of invalid input but the result also return MessageComposeResultSent.

Can anyone help me to answer this question? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when your iPhone suddenly loses connection to Wifi/Cellular, your SMS will fail to send which will return `MessageComposeResultFailed`.

Comment: it seems that it is difficult to make this case happen. Thank you. I'll try your way.